# Can't boot because root volume out of space (virtualbox)

Tags: boot, partitioning, virtualbox

Virtualbox hangs with a black screen while booting Ubuntu. I was running out of space on the root volume and needed to backup files to a shared drive on the host OS, but got an error that I didn't have access (worked fine before with same linux user acct). So I rebooted to try login again and now it just freezes.
Is there anyway to recover some data from the the guest OS?

Comment: host OS is Win10

Comment: If insufficient space exists in $HOME, a GUI login cannot proceed.  A text login however should work; so you can fix your space issues using terminal commands via text login (though lack of space in $HOME will cause what is commonly referred to as *login loop* and not an error, but I'd try text login anyway).

Comment: Or just mount that root partition and delete/move some unused stuff. Delete first all stuff in `/tmp` and `/var/tmp`. After that I would move `/var/log` to another partition. This should be enough for a regular login and fixing your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Yep. Boot the guest os from a Live iso image. The you can free space and recover what you need.

To do that you will have to tell the guest machine to boot from the iso again.

good luck..